# How get words from an element of a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, words

How ca I get words from an element of a PHP array and add them to the end of array

example: I have this array

Array
(
    [0] => sql
    [1] => oracle
    [2] => data bases
    [4] => bd download
    [5] => tutorial
)

I want to get

Array
(
    [0] => sql
    [1] => oracle
    [2] => data
    [4] => bd 
    [5] => tutorial
    [6] => bases
    [7] => download
)

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = array('sql', 'oracle', 'data bases', 'bd download', 'tutorial');

$allWords = array();
array_walk(
    $data,
    function($value) use (&$allWords) {
        $allWords = array_merge($allWords, explode(' ', $value));
    }
);

var_dump($allWords);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$raw = array('sql', 'oracle', 'data bases', 'bd download', 'tutorial');
$imploded = implode(' ', $raw);
$usable  = explode(' ', $imploded);
var_dump($usable);
```